# What is the value of z-coordinate in opengl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have just started learning modern opengl using lwjgl 3. I am confused with the coordinate system of opengl.

I know that when you specify the width and height of the window the coordinates are mapped to that width and height.For example if screen width is 600 the coordinate[1,0] will be mapped to[600,0].

What I wanna know is what is the distance value of z Coordinate?

Comment: "*the coordinates are mapped to that width and height*" Which coordinates? At what point during the pipeline are we talking about, and what transforms have been applied beforehand?

Comment: the x and y coordinates are mapped.

Comment: when you draw a triangle if one vertex is [0.5f , 0.5f ,  1f]  in a window whose width is 600 and height 480.It means that the value of x of vertex is 0.5 * 600/2. Similarly, the value of y of vertex is 0.5 * 480/2. So I want to know how is the value of z coordinate is calculated.

Comment: Also no transformations have been applied to the triangle

Comment: This calculation is not correct. The pixel coordinates [0, 600] are addressed by the normalized device coordinates (NDC) which are in the [-1, 1] range. A NDC coordinate of 0.5 would be 450 in pixel coordinates. You might want to read up on [coordinate system here](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems).

Comment: So the x value at the center of screen would be 300 in pixel coordinates.And 0.5 would be 300 +(0.5 * 300).which equals 450.                                                                So what would be the z value of 0.5?

Comment: so the process of coordinates system is liked this.The model is defined in its own local space.then the coordinates  of the model are converted to world coordinates by transforming it.Then, it is converted to view coordinates by applying view matrix transformation.                                BUT,I do not understand what it says in the page that               " The reason it is called clip coordinates is that the transformed vertex (x, y, z) is clipped by comparing with ±w."

Comment: Look up homogenous coordinates and projective transformations.

Comment: ok thanks I will look it up.

Comment: The normalized device coordinates are in range [-1.0, 1.0] (for all 3 components - x, y, z). The x and y component is *mapped* to the viewport rectangle, wich is defined by [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml). the z component is *mapped* to the depth range, which is by default [0.0, 1.0], but can be shrinked by [`glDepthRange`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDepthRange.xhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z coordinate corresponds to depth. It's value is usually the fraction representing the distance of the fragment between the near plane and the far plane, as demonstrated here: [The camera and its near and far planes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioGwS.png). Clipped means that a fragment is not visible.

The z/depth value is used mainly for depth testing, a process which makes objects that are behind other objects (specifically they must be occluded by them) culled. It is best described here (from [learnopengl.com](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Coordinate-Systems)):

> OpenGL stores all its depth information in a z-buffer, also known as a depth buffer. GLFW automatically creates such a buffer for you (just like it has a color-buffer that stores the colors of the output image). The depth is stored within each fragment (as the fragment's z value) and whenever the fragment wants to output its color, OpenGL compares its depth values with the z-buffer and if the current fragment is behind the other fragment it is discarded, otherwise overwritten. This process is called depth testing and is done automatically by OpenGL.

I highly recomend checking out [learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com) even if you are using LWJGL because the majority of what you can find there also applies to it.

Comment: Thanks, found this information to be useful for **Google's Vision API** as well.